# Oracle SQL Multi Update

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Please Edit Pr Number

```
L3970076 to L3970276, 
L3970077 to L3970277, 
L3970078 to L3970278, 
L3970080 to L3970280, 
L3970082 to L3970282, 
L3970083 to L3970283, 
L3970085 to L3970285

SELECT * FROM GNGRB.PRFILE WHERE PRNO IN ('L3970076', 'L3970077', 'L3970078', 'L3970080', 'L3970082', 'L3970083', 'L3970085');
```

How to update it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the strings have the same length and that you always have to edit the 6th character into a '2', this could be enough:

```
update gngrb.prfile
set prno = substr(prno, 1, 5) || '2' || substr(prno, 7)
where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `case` expression:

```
update gngrb.prfile
set prno = case prno
    when 'L3970076' then 'L3970276'
    when 'L3970077' then 'L3970277'
    when 'L3970078' then 'L3970278'
    when 'L3970080' then 'L3970280'
    when 'L3970082' then 'L3970282'
    when 'L3970083' then 'L3970283'
    when 'L3970085' then 'L3970285'
end
where prno in (
    'L3970076', 
    'L3970077', 
    'L3970078', 
    'L3970080', 
    'L3970082', 
    'L3970083', 
    'L3970085'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTR` or `REGEXP_REPLACE` as follows:

```
UPDATE GNGRB.PRFILE
   SET
    PRNO = SUBSTR(PRNO,1) || (SUBSTR(PRNO,2) + 200)
    --PRNO  = REGEXP_REPLACE(PRNO ,'(^.{5})(0)([0-9]{2}$)','\12\3')
 WHERE PRNO IN (
    'L3970076',
    'L3970077',
    'L3970078',
    'L3970080',
    'L3970082',
    'L3970083',
    'L3970085'
);
```